# Gson date deserializing returning Am in place of Pm in some devices

Tags: java, android, date, gson

The following code is for serializing and deserializing the gson object ,this issue is happening in some devices only. Am of the date is converted to Pm

```
//serializing

public static String getJSONTextFromObject(Object msgObject)
{
    String jsonText = null;
    try {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        jsonText = gson.toJson(msgObject);
    }
    catch ( Exception e)
    {           
    }
    return jsonText;
} 

//deseralizing

public static Object getObjectFromJSONText(Class customMsgClass, String jsonMessage)
{           
    if (jsonMessage == null || jsonMessage.isEmpty() || customMsgClass == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    try 
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonMessage, customMsgClass);
    }
    catch ( Throwable e)
    {
        return null; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Actually time is getting back to 12 hours before